# What should I do for bandwidth estimation for video conference

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, bandwidth, vp8

I have been trying to create video conferencing app as a hobby. I dont use webRTC video tracks instead I transfer three stream of video recorded in 100000, 400000 and 800000 bitrate of vp8 video data from media recorder and transfer only the `simpleBlock` and `timecode` data in the datachannel. With this I can get the key frames and adapt video quality based on the bandwidth. We do have a working app and we regularly chat on it.

However I dont have concrete solution to bandwidth estimation just to make sure I can avoid lagging and congestion. Currently I just calculate the time difference to estimate lags and then switch the video but with this I see my video switch to multiple quality a lot.

I also tried to do something like Shaka player but I dont know how can I calcuate the frame rate that is being received as I have `simple blocks` and `timecode` only.

What should I do for bandwidht estimation?

Comment: If you're regularly having chats with the application, can you measure the bandwidth used then do some averages?

Comment: We do can get the bandwidth average but what we need is to estimate the bandwidth for  potential drop / upgrade of the video bitrate in the ongoing call

Answer (score 2):

You can try to implement MOS (Mean Opinion Score) algorithm in your app to use it's values for bandwidth switching. I had been creating a WebRTC video conferencing application and needed to identify the connection / network quality. This open source JS / TS library [webrtc-issue-detector](https://github.com/VLprojects/webrtc-issue-detector) helped to analyse the report and to trigger errors related to existing issues, moreover - calculate MOS. You can check the implementation of MOS algorithm in the code.